# Not able to DeSelect a row at indexpath in UITableView

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I am adding cells dynamically in my UITableView at index position 0. So whenever I add a cell, I want it to be selected , I have a different image for a selected state.So whenever, I add a cell, it will be selected. Now after adding few cells, user might select any cell at any index position. Now when he again starts to add the cell, the previously selected cell should be deselected and newly added cell at index position zero should be selected.

For this, I have written this code

```
- (void)selectRow0
{

    NSLog(@"row:%d",array.count);

    if(row > 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"indexpathoCheck%@",m_selectedCellIndexPath);
        [self tableView:m_tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:m_selectedCellIndexPath];

    }

    if(row > 0)

        m_selectedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [m_tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:m_selectedCellIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        [self tableView:m_tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:m_selectedCellIndexPath];

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    m_selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;     

    TestCell *cell = (TestCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  

    cell.customImageView.image = selectedImage;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


        TestCell *cell = (TestCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.customImageView.image = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working and where are you calling the selectRow0 method?

Comment: Previously selected row is not getting deselected, and I am calling this function immediately after adding a row.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` in the two if blocks.

Try replacing those two lines with:

```
[m_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:m_selectedCellIndexPath];
```

and

```
[m_tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:m_selectedCellIndexPath];
```

Comment: Ok, I will just try it

Comment: Hey, its not working, bcoz, how the image will set in this case

Comment: I still do not know what is not working, as you have never stated it, and you never said  what the `row` variable is.

Comment: row variable is just the count of my dateSource

Comment: The only other thing I can really think of from the amount of code you provided is that your `row` variable might not be what you think it is at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated; 
        // animate between regular and selected state
```

let suppose you want some another image and a text with different color on clicking a cell
you can simply do

```
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{

      [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if(selected)
        {

                self.image  =[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image.png"];
                self.lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        }
    else
   {

                self.image  =[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_ another _image.png"];
                self.lbl.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
   }

}
```

and add this code to your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
 UITableViewCell    *cellClicked;

 if(cellClicked)
    cellClicked.selected=NO;
    cellClicked=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellClicked.selected=YES;
```